# Sorting using parallel processing - mpi4py

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, parallel-processing

I have a 4 raspberry pi cluster and I want to parallelize the sort of a huge array, I have a master node where the array is built using random numbers then I use scatter of `mpi4py` to send part of the array to each node to sort using the `selectionSort`, however when I gather it, the array is sorted in parts, not everything

I've already tried to use the gather from `mpi4py` and used `selectionSort` after the gathering, which gave me the right result however not quite what the task is asking

The code is this one:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data= np.random.randint(1,101,8)
else:
    data = None

data = comm.scatter(data,root=0)

print 'rank ',rank,'has data: ', data

data = selectionSort(data)

new_data = comm.gather(data,root=0)

if rank == 0:
    print 'master collected: ',new_data
```

I want to get the following result:

Using the array `data = [4, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5, 8, 3]`

I get the final array `new_data = [2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3, 8]`

But I want the array like `new_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Comment: What output do you get? What data are given to each worker? How do you imagine the distributed computation will work? Can you ask whoever gave "the task" for clarification?